# How to store base class children in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have base class that is called Entity.
Then I have two child class Tag, and Property that inherits from Entity.
Now I want to have dictionary that stores a List of Entity. But I cannot get it to work. Have a done the inheritance wrongly?

```
Dictionary<string, List<Entity>> baseDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Entity>>();

List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
tags.Add(new Tag("2012"));
tags.Add(new Tag("hello"));
tags.Add(new Tag("lego"));
List<Properties> properties = new List<Properties>();
properties.Add(new Properties("Year"));
properties.Add(new Properties("Phrase"));
properties.Add(new Properties("Type"));

baseDict.Add("Tags", tags);
baseDict.Add("Properties", properties);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

A `List<Derived>` does not automatically inherit from a `List<Base>`, and they cannot be used interchangeably. The reason for this is that a list is a mutable structure, i.e. elements can be added, removed, and modified.
For example, if I have a `List<Dog>` and a `List<Cat>` lists, and I was able to treat them as a `List<Mammal>`, then the following code will be possible:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();  //create a list of dogs
List<Mammal> mammals = dogs;   //reference it as a list of mammals
List<Cats> cats = mammals;  // reference the mammals as a list of cats (!!?!)
Cat tabby = new Cat();
mammals.Add(tabby)   // adds a cat to a list of dogs (!!?!)
```

However, if you do not need lists, just collections, (and you use C# 4 or later), you could define the dictionary as `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Entity>>`. WIth an `IEnumerable` it is not possible to add or modify the collection, just enumerate it, so any funny bussiness is by definition dissalowed. This is called [Generic Type Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), and if you would like to read more on the subject, there are [several great Eric Lippert blogs.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx)

Comment: Could you explain why Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Entity>> work in this case?

Comment: @CuongLe Added some explanation

Answer (score 3):

You have a Dictionary which holds a `List<Entity>` per key (`string`). You need to store the the `List<Tag/Properties>` as `Entities` itself.

```
Dictionary<string, List<Entity>> baseDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Entity>>();

List<Entity> tags = new List<Entity>();
tags.Add(new Tag("2012"));
tags.Add(new Tag("hello"));
tags.Add(new Tag("lego"));

List<Entity> properties = new List<Entity>();
properties.Add(new Properties("Year"));
properties.Add(new Properties("Phrase"));
properties.Add(new Properties("Type"));

baseDict.Add("Tags", tags);
baseDict.Add("Properties", properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you use `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Entity>>` instead.

The reason you cannot use a `List<Tag>` where a `List<Entity>` is expected, is that it would be dangerous to have something that *looks* like a `List<Entity>` (meaning that you can add `Entity` objects to it), but is really a `List<Tag>` (which can only handle `Tag` objects, not instances of other `Entity` subclasses or instances of `Entity` itself). However, `IEnumerable<Entity>` only lets you check the contents of a collection, not add to it, and it is safe to say that everything inside a `List<Tag>` is an `Entity`.